# Why won't Groovy honor my command-line switches?

Tags: groovy, null, command-line-arguments, executable-jar

I have the following Groovy class:

```
class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = System.getProperty("name")
        println "My name is ${name}."
    }
}
```

When I package it up as an executable JAR and then run it (`java -jar myapp.jar -Dname=Earl`), here is the output I get:

> My name is null.

**Why is `name` null and not "*Earl*"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java` executable considers everything that comes after the main class/Jar as an argument to the `main` method. Try `java -Dname=Earl -jar myapp.jar`. (Unless the Jar is a fat Jar or its manifest class path points to the Groovy Jar, you'll have to pass that as well using `-cp`).